# Was Undertale made in GameMaker v1 or v2?

Tags: undertale

Many people say that Toby Fox used GameMaker to make Undertale, but I'm curious -- which version of GameMaker did he use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Undertale was released on September 2015, while GameMaker 2 was released on March 2017 and GameMaker 1 in November 1999.

**It was made with GameMaker 1**. Or GameMaker Studio 1 (GMS1) to be more specific, released in May 2012.